Ubuntu upgrade to 24.04 disables desktop gdm3 ... how do I get the display back? **SOLVED**
Just upgraded Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 and no display. Reinstalling gdm3 as described elsewhere does not work for me. Error is gdm.service is not active, cannot reload. How do I get my display back?
SOLVED:
see Ubuntu bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/2079843

It looks like the primary graphics card (not a GPU) is using mgag200, but also simpledrm is still active because the Matrox driver failed to remove it.
Then it looks like the desktop (or login screen even) might have failed to render for Mesa/Zink reasons
...
Please try setting (uncommenting) WaylandEnable=false in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and then reboot.

Uncommenting that phrase in custom.conf worked for me and I now have the desktop.

Install another DM like lightdm and see if that works for now

That worked, @Amirreza ... However, while /etc/os-release says "Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS", the login screen for lightdm says, "Ubuntu 23.10"
Anyway, I have filed a bug report via ubuntu-bug (now that I can get in via the GUI).
Thanks for your help.
